# Convert table cell text to array

Tags: jquery

```
<tr>
    <td>a</td>
    <td>b</td>
</tr>
```

I know that I can create an array manually and loop over each td and push them in to the array.

But is there any way to make a jquery one-liner that results in an array with the texts?

Desired result:

```
['a', 'b']
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [.map](http://api.jquery.com/map/) with [.get](http://api.jquery.com/get/) as given below to solve this.

```
var values = $('td').map(function(index, item){
    return $(item).text()
}).get()

console.log(values)
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/ZAeYW/)